# Parallel: Limited number of multi-threaded processes

Tags: linux, multi-core, job-control, multi-threaded, gnu-parallel

I'm using GNU parallel to run multiple jobs in parallel like this: `parallel python3 main.py arg ::: args*`.
With single-threaded jobs, I used `-j 100%` to ensure that 1 job is mapped to 1 core.

Now, each job has four threads and I have 32 cores. I want to distribute the jobs such that they do not overlap, i.e., running 8 jobs at a time each on four different cores.
I don't get how to do this. I tried `-j8`, which I thought would limit the number of parallel jobs. But it still starts all jobs at once - and limits them to 8 cores? `-j 25%` didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

Both `-j 8` and `-j 25%` will do the same on a 32 core machine, so if it does not work, then you have found a bug. Make an MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

But first: Get the newest version to make sure you are not being a hit by a bug already fixed.

Comment: Just to clarify: Is `-j` supposed to limit the number of *jobs* running on however many cores or the number of *cores* processing however many jobs?

Comment: -j limits the number of jobs running in parallel at any given time. In GNU Parallel terminology it is called _job slots_.